# Clang flag to suppress creation of files?

Tags: clang, llvm

Is there a CLI flag for clang that will go through the entire compilation process, including assembling and linking, printing all errors or warnings, but will not create files on the disk?

In particular, I don't need any `.out` files, nor object (`.o`) files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're generating a single file, you can use the `-o` option to choose the output file, so `-o /dev/null` will just get rid of the output without generating any file. You'll still get warnings and errors printed to stderr.

This works in both gcc and clang.